# Rails & ActiveRecord - Different validations for on: :create and on: :update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want a `User` model creation/validation/update system with the following properties:

**Requirement 1**

When a `User` is first created, the `:name`, `:email`, and `:password` attributes should all be present, otherwise the creation save should fail.

**Requirement 2**

When a `User` is updated, these three attributes can be updated individually, so the update save can go ahead if one or two of them are blank.

Simple, common requirements right?? I'm not so sure. The obvious way to meet the first requirement is in `User` model `validations` with `presence: true` for all three:

**user.rb**

```
validates :name,      length: {maximum: 50},           presence: true
validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, presence: true
validates :password,  length: {minimum: 6},            presence: true
```

So from here, how do we meet the second requirement?

**Attempt 1**

Add `on: :create` to the validations:

```
validates :name,      length: {maximum: 50},           presence: true, on: :create
validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, presence: true, on: :create
validates :password,  length: {minimum: 6},            presence: true, on: :create
```

This is disastrous. If a user tried to update just his `name` by submitting the update form with a new `name` but blank `email` and `password` fields, the `name` would indeed be updated but the `email` and `password` attributes would also be updated to a blank value - `""` - because validation would not be run.

**Attempt 2**

Add `allow_nil: true` to the validations:

```
validates :name,      length: {maximum: 50},           presence: true, allow_nil: true
validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, presence: true, allow_nil: true
validates :password,  length: {minimum: 6},            presence: true, allow_nil: true
```

Equally disastrous. You could create AND update a user with blank attributes.

**Attempt 3**

Only validate if it's a new record or the field isn't blank:

```
validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, presence: true, if: :should_validate?

def should_validate?
  new_record? || email.present?
end
```

This has been accepted as the correct solution elsewhere on Stackoverflow but correct me if I'm wrong, isn't it also disastrous? If you update the model with a blank `email` field, `should_validate?` will return `false`, email validation won't run, and the database will be updated with a blank `email`.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this "solution" would work if not **validating** also meant not **updating**, but that's not true is it? If you don't run a validation, the attribute will still be saved to the database right??

**Attempt 4**

In the controller, remove the attribute from `params` if it's blank:

**user.rb**

```
validates :name,      length: {maximum: 50},           presence: true
validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, presence: true
validates :password,  length: {minimum: 6},            presence: true
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def update
  params[:user].delete(:name)     if params[:user][:name].blank?
  params[:user].delete(:email)    if params[:user][:email].blank?
  params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?

  if @user.update_attributes(update_user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Edit Successful."
    redirect_to @user
  else
    @title = "Edit user"
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def update_user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
end
```

This doesn't work because of `presence: true` in the validation. If any of the attributes were not present in `params`, the validation fails, and the record is not updated.

Again, this has been accepted as the correct solution elsewhere on Stackoverflow, so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something somewhere, please tell me where?!

**Attempt 5**

Remove the attribute from `params` if it's blank, and remove `presence: true` from validations:

**user.rb**

```
validates :name,      length: {maximum: 50}
validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
validates :password,  length: {minimum: 6}
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def update
  params[:user].delete(:name)     if params[:user][:name].blank?
  params[:user].delete(:email)    if params[:user][:email].blank?
  params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?

  if @user.update_attributes(update_user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Edit Successful."
    redirect_to @user
  else
    @title = "Edit user"
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

This doesn't work. We've achieved Requirement 2 but destroyed Requirement 1. With this "solution", you can indeed update individual attributes of the record, but you can also **create** a new record with blank attributes.

**Attempt 6**

The only possible solution I can see is to have different validations for `on: :create` and `on: :update`. You insist on `presence: true` if you're creating the record, but remove `presence: true` if you're updating the record. You also need to include the blank attribute removal in the controller:

**user.rb**

```
validates :name,      length: {maximum: 50},           presence: true, on: :create
validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, presence: true, on: :create
validates :password,  length: {minimum: 6},            presence: true, on: :create

validates :name,      length: {maximum: 50},           on: :update
validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, on: :update
validates :password,  length: {minimum: 6},            on: :update
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def update
  params[:user].delete(:name)     if params[:user][:name].blank?
  params[:user].delete(:email)    if params[:user][:email].blank?
  params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?

  if @user.update_attributes(update_user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Edit Successful."
    redirect_to @user
  else
    @title = "Edit user"
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Is this allowed?? Would it work?? Have I completely missed the correct solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you want to save name, email to be nil on update? I think there is no needs to update name, email individually. you just make changes in the field you want like name or email dont make other filed blank simple.

Comment: Definitely not. Name and email should never be updated to nil.

Comment: just posted solution have a look

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to save name, email to be nil on update? I think there is no needs to update name, email individually. you just make changes in the field you want like name or email dont make other filed blank simple.

If you want user name, email update individually just create the setter method under user model like this:

```
def name=(val)
  val = name if val.blank?
  self.write_attribute(name: val)
end

def email=(val)
  val = email if val.blank?
  self.write_attribute(email: val)
end
```

There is no needs to write separate validation for update user.

```
validates :name,      length: {maximum: 50},           presence: true
validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, presence: true
validates :password,  length: {minimum: 6},            presence: true
```

You have not permitted user params while updating records. you probably get exception for this if you are using rails 4. make sure you permit the params before create or updating records like this in users_controller :

```
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
end
```

so you update action will be :

```
def update
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Edit Successful."
    redirect_to @user
  else
    @title = "Edit user"
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to have strong parameters in the question - I've corrected it.

Comment: Are you saying that Attempt 4 would work? As far as I can tell your solution is Attempt 4. Would not `presence: true` in the validation prevent this from working?

Comment: If you want solution 4 work you needs to add setter method for email, name and password to handle blank value. if value is not present then it will simply take old value

Comment: I have updated the setter method in answer just copy it to user model then it should work. Dont make any changes in validation part